# How to upload file using angular4 rest API and spring-boot

Tags: spring, angular, rest, api, spring-boot

i implemented this part of code with spring for the backend part

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String message = "";
        try {
            sp.store(file);
            files.add(file.getOriginalFilename());

            message = "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "FAIL to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(message);
        }
    }
```

and fo the angular part i have this for the frontend but  i have an error in the hhtpRequest the /post

```
pushFileToStorage(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', file);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/post', formdata, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text'
    });




    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

Comment: `but i have an error in the hhtpRequest the /post` then you should attach this error to your question

Comment: BTW. Your mapping is `/upload`, but from Angular you request `/post`. Isn't that a root of error?